# Actian/Pervasive PSQL Zen 13.30 error 46 random ocurrences

Tags: pervasive, zen, btrieve, actian

We currently use Actian PSQL Database in our core business application for more than 10 years. In the las few days, users actions using the application, randomly trigger error 46, which is related with "permissions issues", but what really happens is that for unknown reasons, a table becomes "locked" with a Read-Only lock. We normally have to disconnect users by killing the task, ion order for the lock to be released.

This error, if not solved, causes a domino effect for every user that tries to concurrently access the table, causing lots of inconveniences in our daily operations.

We ease the effects of the problem, performing a manual rebuild of the table involved, at times also stop and restart services, and even reboot the server.

The error keeps appearinf for no apparent reason. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Usually when a status 46 occurs randomly, it can be traced to another program (antivirus, backup, etc) opening the file.  Check to make sure nothing else is opening the file.

Comment: Error 46: " Access to the requested file is denied" (see: https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv13/index.html#page/codes%2F1statcod.htm%23ww179308 )  Which is way more specific then "related to permission issues".

Comment: thanks, it seems mirtheil's comment nailed it. We actually had a backup software operating at certain times, and eliminated all btr files from the request. So far no new ocurrence of the error